# AppSync with DynamoDB "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: name"

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm working in the AWS console.
When I executed the following function on the query screen,
"Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: name" has occurred.
I'm renaming it with "expressionAttributeNames", why?

```json
{
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expressionAttributeNames": {"#abc": "name"},
        "expression": "#abc = :abc",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":abc" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use any attribute name in a key condition expression, provided that the first character is a-z or A-Z and the second character (if present) is a-z, A-Z, or 0-9. In addition, the attribute name must not be a DynamoDB reserved word. **The word "name" is already reserved by DynamoDB**. Check all reserved words here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

Comment: Thank you. understood.